# {debug} dumps nothing in smarty

Tags: debugging, smarty

I'm trying to find defined variables in a smarty template using `{debug}` tag.
But it dumps nothing!
What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm, maybe you are searching for `{debug}` tag instead?

Read more here:

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.debug.tpl
>   http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/chapter.debugging.console.tpl

Remember that calling `{debug}` a window with all Smarty assigned variable will popup on page loading. So, make sure you do not prevent popup to appears in your browser settings.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Yes it was a typo I mean {debug} as I mentioned in title correctly. You are right my browser blocked its popup.